# How can I detect changes in an object inside an Angular8 service?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have an object in a service, testProfile, which changes by many components. I want to call a method, saveToLocalStorage() from another service to save the changes of the testProfile object. How can I detect when the change happens in testProfile?

My code so far:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProfileService  {

  testProfile: ProfileInterface;
  private profileChangeWatcher = new Subject<ProfileInterface>(); 

  constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService ) {

      this.testProfile = this.createProfile(this.localStorageService.loadProfile('testProfile'));
     
   }

   saveProfileChanges() {
      this.profileChangeWatcher.next(this.testProfile);
      this.localStorageService.saveToLocalStorage(this.testProfile);
  }
 
   createProfile(profileData: ProfileInterface): ProfileInterface {

    return new ProfileModel().init(profileData);
  }

}
```

Comment: after `saveToLocalStorage` function just use another Observable which will emit the latest data

Comment: i added this to the code: `this.profileChangeWatcher.subscribe((value)=> {
      
      this.localStorageService.saveToLocalStorage(this.testProfile);

    })`    Where should i call the saveProfileChanges() method?

Comment: Can you provide me a Stackblitz demo?